# Autocorrelation of a sine wave

Tags: time-series, correlation

I would like to know the meaning of an autocorrelation graph of a sine wave. When the time lag is 0, then the autocorrelation should give the highest value of 1 since a copy of the signal is completely correlated to itself. By this logic, after a time equal to the period of the signal, the correlation should again be maximum since the shifted signal is again the signal itself. However, when I plot the correlation in python, I get a function which keeps increasing which goes against my intuition that the correlation function should be periodic. Can anyone please explain why the autocorrelation shows this trend in its graphical form?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
time = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1);
y = np.sin(time)
result = np.correlate(y, y, mode='full')
plt.plot(result[:int(result.size/2 )])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The autocorrelation of a deterministic process is always zero. Correlation refers to the tendency of two random variables to move in the same direction. If you look at a deterministic function like $f(t) = \sin(t)$, then the value of the function at time $t$ does not depend at all on the value at time $t-s$, because that value is fixed.
Of course, `np.correlate` will output some values, but the interpretation of these values as autocorrelation is invalid.
Your intuition sounds more like you are thinking about the ratio $\sin(t) / \sin(t-s).$

Comment: @EliasStrehle I am trying to detect patterns in a signal. My train of thought was, If autocorrelation worked like I thought it did, then i would be able to detect  periodic regions in a signal with the length of the time period being the distant between two maximas in the autocorrelation plot. Like you said my thinking might be wrong. I wanted your opinion on this. In addition to this, do you know any other simple way to detect cycles in a signal? I guess RNNs could do it, but I feel that would be overkill for my application.

Comment: @Toros91 the trend is similar with mode = 'same' and mode='full'

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not have a problem here. The way `np.correlate` is implemented, you get the negative delay values first. If you plotted your entire signal, it would look as expected. Run `plt.plot(result)` and you will get

[image]

The maximum is at 100 and represents zero delay. That the maximum is so high, is because `np.correlate` does not normalize the function, but just computes the sum, as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html)

> This function computes the correlation as generally defined in signal
>   processing texts:
>
> `c_{av}[k] = sum_n a[n+k] * conj(v[n])`
>
> with a and v sequences being zero-padded where necessary and conj
>   being the conjugate.

That the acf decays for your signal and for delays larger or smaller than zero is due to its finite length. For an infinite signal, you would be able to see the periodicity without decay.